# Access denied for Network Share using Windows DIR, but allowed for Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

I work in an large, Windows-centric enterprise that relies on network shared drives. My experience for years has been that if Windows Explorer can display the folder contents of a network shared folder, then the Windows DIR command can do the same. Yesterday, I ran into a case where that is not true.

1. I can put `\\NETWORK-SHARE-NAME\Folder Name` in the Windows Explorer, and it displays the contents.
2. If I open a Windows PowerShell, and type `dir \\NETWORK-SHARE-NAME\Folder Name`, it lists the contents successfully.
3. If I open a Command Prompt, and type `dir \\NETWORK-SHARE-NAME\Folder Name`, it responds "Access Denied."
4. If I first map `\\NETWORK-SHARE-NAME\Folder Name` to a drive letter, like `R:`, then `dir R:\` works in a Command Prompt.

Why would these be different? What do I need to look for in the Security permissions of the shared folder to correct this?

Comment: Related to https://superuser.com/questions/905196/dir-command-not-working-on-one-unc-share